# CSS only slider- buttons active state to inherit the hover background color?

Tags: css, image, slider

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brumbul/VtSKY/1/)

Hi everyone! I am guessing this might turn our to be a very silly question, but I have blocked... There is a link to JS fiddle with a very simple CSS only image slider. What I want to achieve is when a certain image is selected, I want the coresponding box underneath to remain orange. 
Any hints will be highly appreaciated :)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #images
    {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }

        #images img
        {
            background-color:#ffffff;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: -400px;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all linear 500ms;
            -o-transition: all linear 500ms;
            -moz-transition: all linear 500ms;
            -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
        }

            #images img:target
            {
                left: 0;
                z-index: 9;
                opacity: 1;
            }

            #images img:first-child
            {
                left: 0;
                opacity: 1;
            }
    #slider
    {
        width:300px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    #slider a
    {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #808080;
        padding: 1% 7% 1% 7%; 
        color: #808080;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

        #slider a:hover
        {
            background: #ff6a00;
            color: #ff6a00;
        }
    #shadowbox
    {
     border-radius: 10px;
     -o-border-radius:10px;
     -webkit-border-radius:10px;
     -moz-border-radius:10px;
     padding-top:5px;
     padding-bottom:5px;
     width: 400px;
     height: auto;
     box-shadow: #808080 0 0 7px;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="shadowbox">
<div id="images">
    <img id="image1" src="A-06.png" />
    <img id="image2" src="A-07.png" />
    <img id="image3" src="A-05.png" />
    <img id="image4" src="Images_Test-01.png" />
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <a href="#image1">.</a>
    <a href="#image2">.</a>
    <a href="#image3">.</a>
    <a href="#image4">.</a>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The boxes do stay gray when an image is displayed. Do you mean they should stay orange instead?

Comment: Yeah, I mean orange :) My bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a JQUERY code that would help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").css("background-color","#808080");
        $(this).css("background-color","#ff6a00");
  });
});
```

see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VtSKY/2/)

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier with JS, of course. The only way I can think to do this with CSS alone would be to place the images inside the `<a>`s, so that the buttons can share the `:target` status. So, a bit of recoding involved. :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I think I will just add JS and end "the drama" :)

Comment: Yes ... as they say, "choose your battles". :-)